# Pandas: insert a new row in pandas dataframe to populate with dates

Tags: excel, pandas, python-datetime

My excel file has following data:

[image]

I would like to populate a new row with dates for that particular month starting from first Monday of that month.

Example:

For May 2020 it should be as follows:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

The dates are in d/m/yyyy format.

Is there any way to do this via code?

I have tried manually inserting the values but it is hectic to do it manually and also it diminishes all the purpose of coding.

Comment: Please dont post images. Post it as code. Also post sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from month and year number. For your example, May 2020, the are:

```
monthNo = 5
yearNo = 2020
```

So the start of month date can be computed as:

```
myDate = pd.to_datetime(f'{yearNo}-{monthNo:02}-01')
```

(*Timestamp('2020-05-01 00:00:00')*)

Then let's define offsets to Monday and to the end of month:

```
mondayOffs = pd.offsets.Week(0, weekday=0)
eoMonthOffset = pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

To compute the date of first Monday in the selected month and the
end of this month, run:

```
startDate = monOffs.rollforward(myDate)
endDate = eoMonthOffset.rollforward(myDate)
```

getting:

```
Timestamp('2020-05-04 00:00:00')
Timestamp('2020-05-31 00:00:00')
```

To generate a sequence of dates between the above dates, run:

```
seq = pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate)
```

And the final step, conversion to your desired format you can achieve running:

```
dates = seq.strftime('%#d/%#m/%Y').tolist()
```

The result, compressed a bit (several dates in a single line), is:

```
['4/5/2020',  '5/5/2020',  '6/5/2020',  '7/5/2020',  '8/5/2020',
 '9/5/2020',  '10/5/2020', '11/5/2020', '12/5/2020', '13/5/2020',
 '14/5/2020', '15/5/2020', '16/5/2020', '17/5/2020', '18/5/2020',
 '19/5/2020', '20/5/2020', '21/5/2020', '22/5/2020', '23/5/2020',
 '24/5/2020', '25/5/2020', '26/5/2020', '27/5/2020', '28/5/2020',
 '29/5/2020', '30/5/2020', '31/5/2020']
```

Now it is up to you how you save it in a DataFrame and then save this
DataFrame in an Excel file.

Unfortunately, your pictures are **absolutely** unreadable, so I don't know
how to proceed any further.

Comment: Thank You so much for your response. It was perfect. I created a dataframe of this sequence and then did concat with my original dataframe so that i could relate the date and value (from original df).